# How to get photos to sync in order on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, photos

I understand how to sync photos to my iPhone but they seem to be placed on the phone in a rather random order. I've tried numerous changes to the photos but they don't appear to be organized by date, size, or alphabetically by name.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you syncing from mac or PC? Are you syncing using iTunes or some other application outside of it? Are you talking about the camera roll, Photo Stream, or a synced folder?

Answer (score 1):

They are sorted in order of EXIF creation date, which is not necessarily the same as the Date Created shown by the finder.

You can use `exiftool` to view and also set these dates to sort your images...

```
exiftool -overwrite_original_in_place -CreateDate="2008:12:18 12:34:56.78"  MyImage.JPG
```

Answer (score 0):

When you sync with iTunes, sync them into a specific folder and always use this folder. and Don't change their order and select in iTunes Sync Photos.